# Do have Geodesic equation of motions (GR) have any practical use in control theory to control e.g. a rocket on Lunar/Mars space flights?

Tags: general-relativity

I just wonder, if Geodesic equation of motions derived from the GR field equations have any practical application in control theory? So far all books I came across always use Newtonian Forces to create a dynamic model of e.g. a rocket. (Usually  used in an optimal control approach.)

My assumption: Geodesic equation of motions have so far no practical relevance in control theory. They are just used to describe motions/paths of particles/heavy objects in astrophysics? And the progress of humanity is still too underdeveloped to control e.g. heavy objects in space-time like the trajectory o f the moon?

Comment: Accounting for GR in a trip to the moon [doesn't seem to be worth it](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/170962/).