# Spacetime and its contribution to space science

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, estimation, rocket-science, space-mission

Does the launching of a satellite need the consideration of the general theory of relativity (GR)?

Comment: Related, though not a duplicate: [Could we send a man safely to the Moon in a rocket without knowledge of general relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/170962/)

Comment: Have you tried to make a back-of-the-envelope calculation to see if GR effects are relevant?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Newtonian physics would be sufficient to launch and orbit a satellite. But any equipment, sensors, or experiments on board that required exact timing might need to take into account relativistic time dilations from speed and gravity.

Comment: But the general theory isn't used right?

Comment: General relativity is the “gravity” part of this answer. Without corrections from GR, GPS systems wouldn’t function properly.

Comment: @Ahitagni GR's effect is approximately $-2$ times SR's effect, so if you neglect GR you get a sign error.

Comment: So GR is considered right.... thankyou to all of you....thanks for the help guys... you-all are the best

Comment: @Ahitagni In general when it comes to physics things aren't considered right so much as useful. It's possible that GR is "wrong",  just as Newtonian mechanics is (and Aristotle's physics was before it) but we haven't really got a better model yet.

Comment: @origimbo The sentence makes more sense as "So GR is considered, right". The OP omitted the comma in the first comment, too.

Comment: @BobKnighton They would just add on an extra factor and not understand why it's there, but they would make it work.

Comment: @user253751 I'm not quite sure I understand your comment.

Comment: GPS would still work if humans didn't know about relativity.

Comment: @user253751 yes but we would wonder why we had to keep resetting the clocks

Answer (score 4):

No. Newtonian gravity is sufficient.